# Reflection com property decorator no typescript não funciona

Tags: reflexão, typescript, decorator-pattern

Estou tentando criar um decorator (NonExportable) para informar quais campos de uma classe não devem ser exportados. Segue código:

**nonexportable-decorators.ts**

```
const NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY = Symbol("NonExportable");

export default function NonExportable() {
   return Reflect.metadata(NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY, true);
}

export function isNonExportable (target: any, propertyKey: string): boolean {
   return Reflect.getMetadata(NON_EXPORTABLE_KEY, target, propertyKey);
}
```

O decorator está sendo utilizado no modelo "pessoaFisica", conforma apresentado abaixo:

**pessoaFisica.ts**

```
import NonExportable from "../util/nonexportable-decorator"

export class Contribuinte {
    ni: string; 
    @NonExportable()    
    cpf: number;
    @NonExportable()    
    cnpjEstabelecimento: number;
}
```

Contudo, aparentemente não está sendo gravado nada no metadata, haja vista que ao executar a função **Reflect.isNonExportable** é retornado um valor **undefined**. Dessa forma, sempre é retornado false por **isNonExportable**. O que estou fazendo de errado?